# Populate an html <img> with AJAX PHP request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys so I'm trying to create an OOP style of this [captcha maker](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/captcha/#send_feedback) using PHP

I have this `Captcha` class which would handle the actual making of the captcha image

```
class Captcha{

    private $image;
    private $background;
    private $linecolor;
    private $textcolor;

    private $text;
    private $possible;
    private $possibleLen;
    private $randText;

    public function getCaptcha(){
        $image = $this->image;
        $linecolor = $this->linecolor;
        $textcolor = $this->textcolor;

        $text = $this->text;
        $possible= $this->possible;
        $possibleLen = $this->possibleLen;
        $randText = $this->randText;

        // set the image size
        $image = @imagecreatetruecolor(150, 50) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        // set colors to the image
        $background = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 250, 250); // color white
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);

        $linecolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 112, 138, 144); //color gray
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 49, 79, 79); //color greenish

        //draw random lines on canvas
        for($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            imagesetthickness($image, rand(1,3));
            imageline($image, 0, rand(0,30), 120, rand(0,30), $linecolor);
        }

        session_start();

        // generate random text
        $text = "";
        $possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        $possibleLen = strlen($possible);

        for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
            $randText = $possible[rand(0, $possibleLen - 1)];
            $text .= $randText;
            imagechar($image, rand(3, 5), $i, rand(2, 14), $randText, $textcolor);
        }

        // record digits in session variable
        $_SESSION['captcha'] = $text;

        return json_encode(array('image'=>$image));
    }
}
```

And I have this `handler.php` file which would call method of the `Captcha` class:

```
require_once 'captcha.php';

if(empty($_POST['genCaptcha'])){
    return;
}

if(isset( $_POST['genCaptcha'] )) {
    $captcha = new Captcha();
    $result = $captcha->getCaptcha();
}

echo $result;
```

And finally this is my html and jquery code which would send an ajax request to the `handler.php` file

```
<?php

    require_once 'captcha.php';
    require_once 'handler.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><img id="captchaImg" src="" width="120" height="30" border="1" alt="CAPTCHA"></p>
    <button id="genCaptcha" type="button">Generate Captcha</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#genCaptcha').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:"handler.php",
                data: {genCaptcha:'1'},
                success: function(data){
                    var base64Image = data.image;
                    $('#captchaImg').attr('src','data:image...'+base64Image);
                },
                error: function (req, status, err) {
                    console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
```

But I'm just getting an `undefined` result in my ajax success callback

Thank you for anyone that can help me!

Comment: in `getCaptcha()` you should only `return` the json, because you echo it later in `handler.php`

Comment: you are using AJAX to call handler.php but you are also calling it on the HTML page using `require_once`

Comment: dataType should be `json`, or leave it at all. jQuery will find out on it's own.

Comment: @Jeff I tried returning the json ing the `getCaptcha()` method and removed the `dataType` in my ajax request but it still doesn't work. I tried putting an alaert inside the `success` callback in the ajax and it will run everytime I will try to generate the captcha. But unfortunately the <img> of the captcha doesn't update at all

Comment: I think AJAX is returning a string. You will have to parse it using `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @JosanIracheta I tried parsing it using `JSON.parse` and tried getting data.image but it will give this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: output the response to the console to see what it gives you: `console.log(data);`

Comment: @JosanIracheta There's a warning when i tried `console.log(data)` it says `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Captcha::__construct()` Am I missing something in my constructor?

Comment: @ZyxSun did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Since you passed arguments into your `__constructor()`, you have to pass those arguments when you create a new `class`. Simply remove the arguments from the constructor and it should work.

```
//if you have this
__construct($image, $background, $linecolor, $textcolor)
//class should be called like this
$captcha = new Captcha($image,$background,$linecolor,$textcolor);

//change it to this
__construct()
//since you call it like this
$captcha = new Captcha();
```

Comment: oh my god i forgot about that. Now that I removed the arguments from the constructor it now says that my `$image` variable in my class is undefined.`Notice: Undefined variable: image`

Comment: @ZyxSun in your class, whenever you mention $image, it should actually be `$this->image`

Comment: yeah I'm using ` $this->image` in my class but I don't know why it is still undefined

Comment: @ZyxSun in `getCaptcha()` you are referencing `$image` but it should be `$this->image`. Whenever you are referring to `private $image`, you have to use it like `$this->image`

Comment: Do I need to initialize every property i will use in a method or is there a way to initialize them in one section? I don't want to repeatedly using `$image = $this->image;` in every method in a class

Comment: @ZyxSun the properties were already initialized at the top of the class when you called `private $image`. But in order to use that property, you need to call it like so: `$this->image`

Comment: I see. Now I deleted the contructor (updated code above) and just used a single method in order to clean things up. But now I'm just getting an `undefined` variable in my AJAX request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145764/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-zyx-sun).